# Invaild call when using image from array when use require method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image

I'm trying to display image by map an array of image, but i faced this error `Invalid call at line 13: require(item)`

Here is the code

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import {Image, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';

export default function ImageShow() {
  const imagePath = ['./Ellipse2.png', './Ellipse3.png'];
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      {imagePath.map((item, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={index}
          style={{width: 80, height: 80, borderColor: 'grey', borderWidth: 1}}>
          <Image source={require(item)} />.  ==> ERROR HERE
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Image path is correct, i try to change `item` with path to item, and it work, so it not because of path, but i still don't know how to display multi image at the sametime, using expo

Please help, thank a lots

Comment: How can you show multiple images into single component? If you want to show multiple images then you have to use Flatlist.

Comment: The error message might be different but the issue is same, you can't use dynamic require to import images in react native. [Static Image Resources - React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources) Specifically `In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.`

Comment: update your image array like this  `const imagePath = [require('./Ellipse2.png'), require('./Ellipse3.png')];`

Comment: @maddy this is the answer, thank you